# How to integrate Percy.io with Gerrit (Repository Integrations)?

Tags: jenkins, integration, gerrit, visual-testing

I am working on a Visual Regression Testing project, that requires Percy. I followed the instructions for Repository Integrations. The instructions only show 'Connect your GitHub or GitLab repositories to add visual testing to pull/merge requests.', but I want to integrate with Gerrit. And also Jenkins, I cannot find any relative stuff that helps me for the integration on manage Jenkins page as I follow the instructions on Percy.

Answer (score 1):

While Percy doesn't have a native Gerrit integration yet, you can use [Percy webhooks](https://docs.percy.io/docs/webhooks) to get notifications about when Percy builds are finished, visual changes are ready for review, and when they've been reviewed and approved, which you could use to set statuses in Gerrit. For Jenkins, please see https://docs.percy.io/docs/jenkins — I would suggest you try getting the local setup working first with your application and then go from there, since it should be pretty easy to port that setup into your CI system (just need to set PERCY_TOKEN environment variable).